# Unable to Start other applications after Keycloak using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, keycloak, bash-completion

I'm trying to start multiple application using bash script.

The Criteria is keycloak must be started first and then other 2 applications as those would be require keycloak access.

The Issue I'm Facing is once my script start Keyclaok then it is not releasing the control over console and other applications can not be started with the next step mentioned in my script.

Is there a way that once keyckcloak is started then the script can execute other piece of code in my script to start other applications ?

```
if(Condition) {
   Start Keycloak
}
fi

if(Condition) {
   Start App1
}
fi

if(Condition) {
   Start App2
}
fi
```

Comment: Did you try to start this `keycloak` in background (`command &`)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the apps in the background. This can be done using the 'bg' command, or by appending '&' to the end.

For instance, `bg start keycloak`, or `start keycloak &`. Some apps have an option to start them in the background as a demon, so read through the program help.

Comment: Does it give you an error, or what happens?